# Jekyll Config Multiple Files

Tags: jekyll

As the [doc](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/) mentions, we should be able to write:

```
jekyll build --config "_config.yml, _config.en.yml"
```

Instead, I receive:

```
Fatal: The configuration file ' _config.en.yml' could not be found.
```

While the file actually exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a comma-separated list. You're separating it with a comma and a space.

Comment: I agree. I use 2 config files, separating them with a comma and no space.

Answer (score 9):

Remove the space after the coma.

```
jekyll build --config "_config.yml,_config.en.yml"
```

Comment: There's no need for quotes if the file names don't contain any space, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

For others coming here and not finding the answer they need:

It could also be that you are running the build script from another folder where the config files are (like a git `post-receive` hook)

In which case you'd need to do tweak the example scripts to include the `$CONFIG` as follow:

```
TMP_GIT_CLONE=$HOME/tmp_git/your_domain
GEMFILE=$TMP_GIT_CLONE/Gemfile  
PUBLIC_WWW=/var/www/html/your_domain
CONFIG=$TMP_GIT_CLONE/_config.yml,$TMP_GIT_CLONE/_config_dev.yml  
git clone $GIT_REPO $TMP_GIT_CLONE
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$GEMFILE bundle install
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$GEMFILE bundle exec jekyll build -s $TMP_GIT_CLONE -d $PUBLIC_WWW --config $CONFIG
```