# Exclude files based on the JEKYLL_ENV?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

In a Jekyll site one excludes files like this:

```
exclude:
    - "*.json"
    - "Gemfile*"
    - "*.txt"
    - vendor
    - README.md
    - somefile.html
```

So to create the production build I run: `$ JEKYLL_ENV=production bundle exec jekyll build`

How can I exclude the somefile.html file *only* when I run the production ENV?

Comment: What is someone.html or how are you using it?

Comment: In this case it is a static file that I need in _site when it is dev but not in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could try using a specific config file for production and one for development. In the production you could exclude the files using exclude [as described here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/).

Then run:

`jekyll build --trace --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml`

or

`jekyll build --trace --config _config.yml,_config_prod.yml`

In the _config.yml you'd set generic settings, and in the config with the environment suffix you'd set a environment specific configuration.

---

The trace flag is optional, it will help setting it up since it will show occuring errors.

`optional: -t, --trace        Show the full backtrace when an error occurs`

Comment: Yes, thanks for sharing, also possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30899655/1501285

Comment: Isn't that the same as stated above however with `"..."`? The trace is optional of course to potentially debug once you're setting it up. I'll add the note.