# Jekyll ignores second configuration file

Tags: jekyll

I’ve created two config files on the root of my site _config.yml and _production.yml.

I’m using NPM to build my site using the following script:

```
  "scripts": {
      "build": "JEKYLL_ENV=production jekyll clean && jekyll build --config _config.yml, _production.yml"
  },
```

But the second file, where i overwrite the Sass output style get’s ignored.

Same result when using `bundle exec`.

I’m using jekyll 3.8.6, node v10.15.0, npm 6.10.2, ruby 2.3.7p456

Any ideas on this ?

Comment: Try without the space after the comma: `jekyll build --config _config.yml,_production.yml`

Comment: Yes, that’s it. A simple space does all the difference. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here [GitHub, 7766](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7766) or on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897871/jekyll-config-multiple-files).

Solution a) skip the space between the comma separated list
`jekyll build --config _config.yml,_production.yml`

Solution b) wrap the config file list with quotes
`jekyll build --config "_config.yml, _production.yml"`